# Are universal characters allowed in PHP explode()

Tags: php, regex

I need to get everything before "On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM,"

I am hoping to get everything before "On xxx, xxx xx, xxxx at xx:xx xx,"

The problem here is that May, 27, and 6 are all variable in length. What is the best tool for this job. Due to my lack of experience with regex I am trying to use explode() but it doesn't appear it can do the job here. Is regex my best option?

[EDIT]

I ended up using a combination of answers. I went with:

preg_match("/(.*)On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon),\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/i", $to, $end);

Comment: why don't you use strtotime() in combination with date() ?

Comment: I still couldn't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: where is the "before" in a string full of values?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I am trying to parse emails from an external server that sends $_POST keys to my script. I need the reply message but it is garbled with the original message. The only way I can think to get the reply message is to grab everything before what I put above.

Comment: So you have a data set like this structure "XXXXXXXXXX On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM", and you want to get the XXXXXXXXXX ?

Comment: @Hamza Thats correct. Thats exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
/On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon),\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/i
```

[EDIT]

As per the comment: I have added support for case insensitive (by adding the `i` modifier to the end of the regex). I have also change the spaces in the expression to `\s` to allow any whitespace character, and added `+` to allow multiples spaces between words.

I haven't changed it to support long day names or short month names, as the questions specified that month name was variable in length but didn't specify day name as being variable. However, it should be trivial enough to add these variants if required.

[EDIT]

```
$to = "Let me know how this response looks..... On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM, Pr";
preg_match("/On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon),\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/i", $to, $end);
```

This code works for the example given in your comment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should supports: short and full name (`Sun` and `Sunday`, `Jan` and `January`), upper/lower case, and multiple whitespaces.

Comment: @bsdnoobz - I was answering the specific question, not providing a generic date regex. The day of week was not one of the fields he specified as being variable length, so I assumed it was fixed at three characters. Conversely, although "May" could have been ambiguous on this point, the month was specified as being variable length, so I provided full month names. Whitespace was also not mentioned in the question, so I assumed it was fixed (as it likely will be if he's getting the input from a single specific source).

Comment: @bsdnoobz - I have edited the answer with *some* of your suggestions (though I suspect this is done more to appease you than for the benefit of the OP)

Comment: Thank you for your help Spudley. I am trying to get your solution to work. I am using the following but coming up with no matches for $to = "Let me know how this response looks..... On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM, Pr"    preg_match("/On\s+(Sun|Sat|Fri|Thu|Wed|Tue|Mon)\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d?\d,\s+\d{4}\s+at\s+\d?\d:\d\d\s+[AP]M,/i", $to, $end);

echo "end 0" . $end[0];

Comment: @DevNewb - Main problem was I'd missed the comma after the day of the week. I've fixed the regex and pasted a working version of the code in your comment into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(.*?) On \w+, \w+ \d?\d, \d+ at \d?\d:\d?\d \w\w,/', 'grab this text here On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM,', $matches);
echo $matches[1];
// echoes 'grab this text here'
```

`(.*?)` matches everything in the beginning, `\w+` matches any alphanumeric character 1 or more times, `\d?\d` matches either one or two digits

Answer (score 0):

a regular expression would work since that's what it was made for: selecting data based on a pattern. You could however explode on ',' (comma) and just implode the first 4 elements together again to form your sentence. I doubt using regular expression will be faster in this case.

Ultimately it's your preference: which is better readable and understandable by you.
The main advantage regular expression would have in this particular case is hat they can extract specific values/patterns, so you could easily have them set aside the month for instance.

```
$dateString = "On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 6:25 AM, some other text here";

// using explode/implode
$result = explode(',',$dateString);

print "we got: " . implode(',', array_slice($result,0,3)) . "\n";

// using regular expression
$pattern = "/On [A-Z,a-z]{3}, [A-Z,a-z]{3} [0-9]+, [0-9]{4} at [0-9,:]+ (?:A|P)M/U";

preg_match($pattern,$dateString,$match);

print "We got: " . $match[0] . "\n";
```

Please also read the [PHP manual, Regular Expressions subsection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) together with an initial [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)

Personally in this case I think reg exp might be overkill both visually and performance wise. Do learn regular expressions though, they can be very helpful at times.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? $match[0] returns On Sun, May 27, 2012 at 7:48 AM? I need everything that comes before what it is returning.

Comment: oh, my mistake then, I misinterpreted your request as wanting to have the date string. Sorry. In that case you'd need to use pattern matching with extraction `$pattern = "/(.*)On [A-Z,a-z]{3}, [A-Z,a-z]{3} [0-9]+, [0-9]{4} at [0-9,:]+ (?:A|P)M/U";

preg_match($pattern,$dateString,$match);

print "We got: " . $match[1] . "\n";
`  and adapt the match. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: the (.*) between / (start of reg exp) and On is what has changed it means that you want any data(.) unlimited times(*) captured (between parentheses) and the result placed in the $match array (first entry is whole string, second entry is first match)